# Getting NPE from Json validate in Reads (reading custom class in Scala)

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I have a situation where I want to read an object like so:

```
Something(first: String, second: GPID)
```

GPID is a wrapper around an Int (see below).

The class can serialize just fine (Write) but when I try to deserialize (Read) and then validate, Play is throwing an NPE.

**Edit**

The example posted above has been simplified. The actual code that I'm working with is a bit more complicated, so I was attempting to create a simple example. This is the actual object I'm working with:

```
case class GPInviteRequest(token: String, userId: Option[GPID] = None, email: Option[String] = None, phoneNumber: Option[GPPhoneNumber] = None)
object GPInviteRequest {
    implicit val readsInvite = Json.reads[GPInviteRequest]
    implicit val writesInvite = Json.writes[GPInviteRequest]
}
```

The GPID type is basically a wrapper around an Int. All of the referenced objects (GPID, GPPhoneNumber) have their own Reads/Writes. In my first attempt, I was getting: `JsError(List((/userId/GPID,List(ValidationError(error.path.missing,WrappedArray())))))`. This was because I wasn't creating well-formed JSON, but so far so good, the server was correctly reporting errors... So, now I've written a test that serializes and then deserializes the object:

```
    "serialize an invite request to/from JSON" in {
        val j1 = Json.toJson(GPInviteRequest("token@ab6f7ad89ce8ff", Option(GPID(1000))))

        println(j1.toString)

        j1.validate[GPInviteRequest].isSuccess must beTrue
    }
```

The GPID is a wrapper around an Int, but, it's Reads method looks like this:

```
object GPID {
    implicit val reads: Reads[GPID] = (
        (__ \ "GPID").read[GPID]
        )
...
```

Ok, so, now when I run the test, here's the output:

```
[info] The invite service should
[error]   ! serialize an invite request to/from JSON
{"token":"token@ab6f7ad89ce8ff","userId":{"GPID":1000}}
[error]    null (JsConstraints.scala:36)
```

Just for completeness, here's the error:

```
[error]    null (JsConstraints.scala:36)
[error] play.api.libs.json.PathReads$$anonfun$at$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(JsConstraints.scala:36)
[error] play.api.libs.json.PathReads$$anonfun$at$1$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(JsConstraints.scala:36)
[error] play.api.libs.json.JsResult$class.flatMap(JsResult.scala:103)
[error] play.api.libs.json.JsSuccess.flatMap(JsResult.scala:9)
[error] play.api.libs.json.PathReads$$anonfun$at$1.apply(JsConstraints.scala:36)
[error] play.api.libs.json.PathReads$$anonfun$at$1.apply(JsConstraints.scala:36)
[error] play.api.libs.json.Reads$$anon$8.reads(Reads.scala:101)
[error] play.api.libs.json.PathReads$$anonfun$nullable$1$$anonfun$apply$7$$anonfun$apply$9.apply(JsConstraints.scala:65)
[error] play.api.libs.json.PathReads$$anonfun$nullable$1$$anonfun$apply$7$$anonfun$apply$9.apply(JsConstraints.scala:63)
[error] play.api.libs.json.JsResult$class.fold(JsResult.scala:76)
[error] play.api.libs.json.JsSuccess.fold(JsResult.scala:9)
[error] play.api.libs.json.PathReads$$anonfun$nullable$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(JsConstraints.scala:61)
[error] play.api.libs.json.PathReads$$anonfun$nullable$1$$anonfun$apply$7.apply(JsConstraints.scala:61)
[error] play.api.libs.json.PathReads$$anonfun$nullable$1.apply(JsConstraints.scala:59)
[error] play.api.libs.json.PathReads$$anonfun$nullable$1.apply(JsConstraints.scala:58)
[error] play.api.libs.json.Reads$$anon$8.reads(Reads.scala:101)
[error] play.api.libs.json.Reads$$anon$3$$anon$4.reads(Reads.scala:81)
[error] play.api.libs.json.Reads$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Reads.scala:28)
[error] play.api.libs.json.Reads$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Reads.scala:28)
[error] play.api.libs.json.Reads$$anon$8.reads(Reads.scala:101)
[error] play.api.libs.json.Reads$$anon$3$$anon$4.reads(Reads.scala:81)
[error] play.api.libs.json.Reads$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Reads.scala:28)
[error] play.api.libs.json.Reads$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Reads.scala:28)
[error] play.api.libs.json.Reads$$anon$8.reads(Reads.scala:101)
[error] play.api.libs.json.Reads$$anon$3$$anon$4.reads(Reads.scala:81)
[error] play.api.libs.json.Reads$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Reads.scala:28)
[error] play.api.libs.json.Reads$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Reads.scala:28)
[error] play.api.libs.json.Reads$$anon$8.reads(Reads.scala:101)
[error] play.api.libs.json.JsValue$class.validate(JsValue.scala:73)
[error] play.api.libs.json.JsObject.validate(JsValue.scala:166)
[error] application.TestInviteServices$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$3$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcZ$sp(TestInviteServices.scala:31)
[error] application.TestInviteServices$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$3$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(TestInviteServices.scala:31)
[error] application.TestInviteServices$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$3$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(TestInviteServices.scala:31)
[error] application.TestInviteServices$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(TestInviteServices.scala:31)
[error] application.TestInviteServices$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$3.apply(TestInviteServices.scala:26)
```

Comment: Edited (rewrote, really) with a test case that is demonstrating the failure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your recursive definition of `Reads[GPID]`. `GPID` is supposed to wrap `Int`, but the `Reads` don't actually show that. `GPID.reads` contains `(__ \ "GPID).read[GPID]` which relies on an implicit `Reads[GPID]` to be in scope. Unfortunately, the compiler allows `GPID.reads` itself to fulfill that need, which throws a `NullPointerException` because it's trying to access itself before it has even been initialized.

```
case class GPID(GPID: Int)

object GPID {
    implicit val reads: Reads[GPID] = (__ \ "GPID").read[GPID]
    implicit val writes: Writes[GPID] = Json.writes[GPID]
}

scala> val gpid = GPID(1234)
gpid: GPID = GPID(1234)

scala> val js = Json.toJson(gpid)
js: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"GPID":1234}

scala> js.validate[GPID]
java.lang.NullPointerException
...
```

To fix this, we simply need to fix the `Reads[GPID]` to not be recursive, which is easy. We really want `read[Int]`, because that's what it wraps. Then we `map` that `Int` into a `GPID`.

```
case class GPID(GPID: Int)

object GPID {
    implicit val reads: Reads[GPID] = (__ \ "GPID").read[Int].map(GPID(_))
    implicit val writes: Writes[GPID] = Json.writes[GPID]
}

scala> js.validate[GPID]
res2: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[GPID] = JsSuccess(GPID(1234),/GPID) // It works!
```

If we incorporate with your other code, it now works:

```
scala> val j1 = Json.toJson(GPInviteRequest("token@ab6f7ad89ce8ff", Option(GPID(1000))))
j1: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = {"token":"token@ab6f7ad89ce8ff","userId":{"GPID":1000}}

scala> j1.validate[GPInviteRequest]
res3: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[GPInviteRequest] = JsSuccess(GPInviteRequest(token@ab6f7ad89ce8ff,Some(GPID(1000)),None),)
```

You haven't shown it, but I have a feeling that `GPPhoneNumber` will have the same problem (assuming it just wraps a `String` and the `Reads` are defined in a similar manner), but the fix will be the same.

Comment: The moment you wrote "recursive" it dawned on me! Thank you so much, that was plaguing me for over day. It turns out the phone number type was fine, since it was using Scala native types (int, string). Really appreciate the help on the GPID reads, I was having trouble getting that right.

Answer (score 1):

What error are you getting specifically? What are you trying to accomplish? This works for me:

```
import play.api.libs.json.Json

case class Person(first: String, middle: Option[String], last: String)

object Person {
  implicit val reads = Json.reads[Person]
}

val json = """{ "first": "Michael", "middle": null, "last": "Kendra"}"""
val json2 = """{ "first": "Michael", "last": "Kendra"}"""


Json.parse(json).validate[Person]
# >> res0: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[Person] = JsSuccess(Person(Michael,None,Kendra),)

Json.parse(json2).validate[Person]
# >> res1: play.api.libs.json.JsResult[Person] = JsSuccess(Person(Michael,None,Kendra),)
```

Comment: I'm going to have to dig deeper, what I'm getting back from our server is: `code: -3
message: "JsError(List((/userId/GPID,List(ValidationError(error.path.missing,WrappedArray())))))"
description: "INCORRECT_PARAMETER"` so obviously there are a few layers here. I had assumed the "path.missing,WrappedArray" meant that a parameter was missing. I'm not entirely sure what the error actually means... (Note: I sanitized my original example; the actual parameters are: token: String, userId: Option[GPID], email: Option[String], phoneNumber: Option[GPPhoneNumber])

Comment: I revised my original post with more details and the actual code (rather than a simplified example).